# Deciphering AWS Glue Out Of Memory and Metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to figure out what my AWS Glue job metrics mean and whats the likely cause of failure

[image]

[image]

From the 2nd chart I note that driver memory (blue) stays relatively constant while some executors fluctuate. The strange thing is it seems most executors are doing nothing? Why is that?

My code: I am reading in a bunch of flights info from Glue data catalog, processing it and writing it out in S3 as parquet files. In this case, I have used predicate push down.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction, regexp_replace, to_timestamp
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, DateType, Row

batches = [
    "12929,14511,9968,15280,16162,17210,10193,14534,12542,13439,16122,9498,13301,12728,13303,16716,13311,12913,13531",
    "12191",
    "10658,11052,9970,13078,17388,10438,17396,17409,12917,17416,12118,12195",
    "9921,9799,15253,16587,15412,17106,17368,13804,15461,19461,16923,16945,13164,9794,10031,25396,15422,10101,17002,14147,13180,11336,13428,9449,25405,16955,10180,11017,12795,12952,10485,12210,25336,17152,16516,16451,16437,15395,13947,10182,11893,11109",
    "11036,17471,17482,16240,10902,17521,12071,12337,15526,17294,15671,12274,10858,10032",
    "13113,11170,14213,18490,17402,10982,12392,12482,15168,9762,10871,11780,10284,10431,16743,15518,10497,13536,10724,14260,16747"
]

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# READ IN FLIGHTS, AIRPORTS, AGENTS TABLES
# NOTE: Bookmarks enabled for flights data catalog
airportsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "...", table_name = "airports")
airportsDF = airportsGDF.toDF()
airportsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("airports")

agentsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "...", table_name = "agents")
agentsRawDF = agentsGDF.toDF()
agentsRawDF.createOrReplaceTempView("agents_raw")

agentsDF = spark.sql("""
    SELECT * FROM agents_raw
    WHERE type IN ('Airline', 'TravelAgent')
""") 
agentsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("agents")

for batch in batches:
    flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "...", table_name = "flights", transformation_ctx="flights", push_down_predicate="""
        querydatetime BETWEEN '2019-01-22' AND '2019-01-31' 
        AND querydestinationplace IN (%s)
    """ % (batch))

    flightsDf = flightsGDF.toDF()
    flightsDf.createOrReplaceTempView("flights")

    resultDf = spark.sql("""
        SELECT 
            f.*, countryName, cityName, airportName, a.name AS agentName,
            CONCAT(f.outboundlegid, '-', f.inboundlegid, '-', f.agent) AS key
        FROM flights f
        LEFT JOIN agents a
        ON cast(f.agent as bigint) = a.id
        LEFT JOIN airports p
        ON cast(f.querydestinationplace as bigint) = p.airportId
    """)
    df = resultDf.withColumn("querydatetime", regexp_replace(resultDf["querydatetime"], "-", "").cast("int"))
    df = resultDf.withColumn("queryoutbounddate", regexp_replace(resultDf["queryoutbounddate"], "-", "").cast("int"))
    df = resultDf.withColumn("queryinbounddate", regexp_replace(resultDf["queryinbounddate"], "-", "").cast("int"))
    df = resultDf.withColumn("outdeparture", to_timestamp(resultDf["outdeparture"], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))
    df = resultDf.withColumn("outarrival", to_timestamp(resultDf["outarrival"], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))
    df = resultDf.withColumn("indeparture", to_timestamp(resultDf["indeparture"], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))
    df = resultDf.withColumn("inarrival", to_timestamp(resultDf["inarrival"], "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))

    print("===LOG:WRITING_RAW===")
    df \
        .write \
        .mode("append") \
        .partitionBy(["countryName", "querydatetime"]) \
        .parquet("s3://...-glue/rawFlights")
    print("===LOG:DONE_WRITING_RAW===")


    df.createOrReplaceTempView("flights")

    # GET DISTINCT DATASET
    distinctKeysDf = resultDf.select(resultDf['key']).distinct
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("distinctKeys")

    def generate_date_series(start, stop):
        return [start + timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).days + 1)]    

    spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(DateType()))


    # GET RELAVENT DATES DATASET
    # CREATE DF FOR PAST 90 DAYS EXCLUDING PAST 7 DAYS
    today = datetime.utcnow().date()
    start = today - timedelta(days = 25) # TODO: CHANGE TO 90
    sevenDaysAgo = today - timedelta(days = 7)
    print(">>> Generate data frame for ", start, " to ", sevenDaysAgo, "... ")
    relaventDatesDf = spark.createDataFrame([
        Row(start=start, stop=sevenDaysAgo)
    ])
    relaventDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("relaventDates")
    spark.sql("SELECT explode(generate_date_series(start, stop)) FROM relaventDates").show()

    print("===LOG:WRITING_EXPANDED===")
    expandedKeyDatesDf = spark.sql("""
        SELECT key, querydatetime
        FROM relaventDates
        CROSS JOIN distinctKeys
    """)
    print("===LOG:DONE_WRITING_EXPANDED===")


    expandedKeyDatesDf \
        .coalesce(1) \
        .write \
        .mode("append") \
        .parquet("s3://...-glue/expanded")

    expandedKeyDatesDf.createOrReplaceTempView("expandedKeyDates")

    cleanedFlightsDf = spark.sql("""
        SELECT e.key AS master_key, e.querydatetime AS master_querydatetime, f.*
        FROM expandedKeyDates e
        LEFT JOIN flights f
        ON e.key = f.key
        AND e.querydatetime = f.querydatetime
        ORDER BY e.key, e.querydatetime
    """)
    print("===LOG:WRITING_CLEANED===")
    cleanedFlightsDf \
        .write \
        .mode("append") \
        .partitionBy(["countryName", "querydatetime"]) \
        .parquet("s3://...-glue/cleanedFlights")
    print("===LOG:DONE_WRITING_CLEANED===")

    print("===LOG:DONE BATCH %s" % (batch))


job.commit()
```

It seem like it failed trying to write the expanded data frame to parquet

```
expandedKeyDatesDf = spark.sql("""
    SELECT key, querydatetime
    FROM relaventDates
    CROSS JOIN distinctKeys
""")
```

But why since this is just joining 2, 1 column data frames

Comment: Did you check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-profile-debug-oom-abnormalities.html? It has some tips how to use Glue metrics to understand OOM issues

Comment: @YuriyBondaruk yes, but it looks like groupFiles are for reading files from S3 and the other one is when reading from a SQL DB. I am reading from data catalog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record to remind myself what solved the problem or at least based on what I can recall:

Use predicate push down to limit data read:

used predicate pushdown to reduce the amount of data read

```
flightsGDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "pinfare", table_name = "flights", transformation_ctx="flights", push_down_predicate="""
    querydatetime BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'
    AND querydestinationplace IN (%s)
""" % (start.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), ",".join(map(lambda s: str(s), arr))))
```

And use broadcast hints like:

```
resultDf = spark.sql("""
    WITH f (
        SELECT
            /*+ BROADCAST(h) */
            /*+ COALESCE(12) */
            CONCAT(f.outboundlegid, '-', f.inboundlegid, '-', f.agent) AS key,
            f.querydatetime,

            f.outboundlegid,
            f.inboundlegid,
            f.agent,
            f.queryoutbounddate,
            f.queryinbounddate,
            f.price,
            f.outdeparture,
            f.outarrival,
            f.indeparture,
            f.inarrival,
            f.querydestinationplace,
            f.numberoutstops,
            CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (out_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END out_is_holiday,
            CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (out_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END out_is_longweekends,
            CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END in_is_holiday,
            CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END in_is_longweekends
        FROM flights f
        CROSS JOIN holidays h
    )
     SELECT
        /*+ BROADCAST(a) */
        /*+ BROADCAST(p) */
        key,
        querydatetime,
        first(outboundlegid) as outboundlegid,
        first(inboundlegid) as inboundlegid,
        first(agent) as agent,
        first(p.countryName) as countryName,
        first(p.airportName) as airportName,
        first(p.airportCode) as airportCode,
        first(a.name) as agentName,
        first(queryoutbounddate) as queryoutbounddate,
        first(queryinbounddate) as queryinbounddate,
        first(price) as price,
        first(outdeparture) as outdeparture,
        first(outarrival) as outarrival,
        first(indeparture) as indeparture,
        first(inarrival) as inarrival,
        first(querydestinationplace) as querydestinationplace,
        first(numberoutstops) as numberoutstops,
        CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_holiday), true)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END out_is_holiday,
        CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_longweekends), true)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END out_is_longweekends,
        CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_holiday), true)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END in_is_holiday,
        CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_longweekends), true)
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END in_is_longweekends
    FROM f
    INNER JOIN agents a
    ON f.agent = a.id
    INNER JOIN airports p
    ON f.querydestinationplace = p.airportId
    GROUP BY
        querydatetime,
        key
""")
```

Answer (score 1):

This chart can display the executors that run from the beginning.
I suppose that new executors were launched in the middle.
Go to CloudWatch Metrics, you will find so many executors were launched.